# Best way to automate expiration dates?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, automation

I'm writing a program that essentially simulates a game of tag. I want users to be able to tag another user, giving the tagged user 24 hours to tag back. If after 24 hours the tagged user has not responded they lose the game. What is the best way to implement a system that will check if 24 hours have passed without user interaction being a requirement? I believe this scenario is very similar to how Snapchat has implemented 'streaks' where users can have a streak if they each snap each other every day for more than 3 days in a row etc. If a user does not send a snap within 24 hours the streak expires automatically.

I am using .net and entity framework core with plans to use an in-memory database to begin with. Any design ideas/code snippets are welcome.

Comment: When you say "they lose the game", do you mean that you need to initiate some kind of notification? If not, why not simply use an expiry date? To be honest, even if you need some kind of notification: use an expiry date and have a service pick up expired tags.

Comment: Yes I'm thinking some kind of notification would be best. I agree with using a service to check the expired tags, but what is good practice when implementing this? Should I be checking against the database every minute? Every hour?

Comment: I would check every minute. And use a Background task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) if running in a asp .net environment

Comment: @kraego this is perfect! Thank you!